# How to handle exception NameError when making function to get path of a module?

Tags: python-3.x, function, exception

I get NameError exception when handling it in the function for getting path of a module

```
def get_path(module):
    import os
    try:
        return os.path.abspath(module.__file__)
    except NameError:
        print("Not found ", module)
```

When I use `get_path(oa)` to test if module "oa" existed, I received `NameError exception` (name 'oa' is not defined) although I handled it in the function above. Please explain this case. Thanks!

Comment: what is `oa`? a string?, because your function is expecting a module object I guess

Comment: It's only any name of module for testing the code, like ```get_path(os)``` or ```get_path(string)```, etc

Comment: are you saying that NameError exception is not caught when it is raised?

Comment: @OzcarNguyen it is not the same a name (string) than a module object. It is not clear to me the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle that execption because your function will not work if you don't import the module first, the name error is being produced when calling the funtion not inside:

```
>>> def get_path(module):
...     import os
...     try:
...         return os.path.abspath(module.__file__)
...     except NameError:
...         print("Not found ", module)
... 
>>> get_path(os)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>> import os
>>> get_path(os)
'/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py'
```

You need to have the module in scope as every other thing in python, if it is not defined it cannot be used.

You can use importlib and this function for example:

import importlib
import os

```
def get_path(module_name):
  try:
    if module_name not in globals().keys():
      module = importlib.__import__(module_name, globals())
      globals()[module_name] = module
    module = globals()[module_name]
    return os.path.abspath(module.__file__)
  except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("Not found module:", module_name)
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulDarkcyanPackage)

Comment: I see. You mean we have to import "module" (eg: os, string,...) before getting its path by that function. How could we make a function that checks if the module had been imported? If yes, return its path, if no, handling ```NameError``` exception?!

Comment: @OzcarNguyen, this handles the base, it is working in the example. If you need to adapt it to your code then you should adapt it, you can not expect that everything will be solved at once. The keys are that you should use a string as module name, check if it is imported already if it is not try to import ant check for the module path. If you have extra exceptions try to handle them as you need.